# Unable to force user to input password after editing profile (Solspace User)

Tags: members, solspace, solspace-user

I am using Solspace User.

Unable to force user to input current password after modifying their profile.

Using this parameter `password_required="y"` or `password_required="yes"` takes no effect. It is not redirecting me to error page or prompting any error message

I am not logged in as Super Admin

```
{exp:user:edit
    group_id="5|6"
    member_id="{segment_3}"
    password_required="yes"
    required="formal_title|first_name|last_name"
    return="teachers/edit_profile/{segment_3}/success"
            error_page="teachers/error"
}

    <input type="text" name="username" value="{username}" placeholder="Email address"/>
    <br>

    <select name="formal_title">
        {select_formal_title}
            <option value="{value}" {selected}>{value}</option>
        {/select_formal_title}
    </select>
    <br>

    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{first_name}" placeholder="First name"/>
    <br>

    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="{last_name}" placeholder="Last name"/>
    <br>



    <input type="password" name="current_password" placeholder="Current Password" />
    <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

{/exp:user:edit}
```

Any ideas? Appreciate for help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Solspace documentation about the `current_password` form field](http://www.solspace.com/docs/user/edit/#f_current_password):

> This form field is available and required in certain instances where the current password is required to update or change certain profile data:
>
> - `password` & `password_confirm` fields are modified (unless the submitter is a Super Admin or in one of the authorized member groups specified in the group_id parameter).
> - `email` field is modified.
> - `username` field is modified.
> - `screen_name` field is modified, unless screen_name_password_required parameter is specified with value of no.
> - `password_required` parameter is specified with value of yes.

Note that `current_password` isn't affected by editing a custom member field.

Also, `current_password` also isn't necessary if you're logged in as a member whose member group has administrative powers, which is controlled by the `group_id=""` parameter. If you remove your group_id from the `group_id=""` parameter in your code above, `current_password` becomes required if you modify any of the above fields mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Removed `group_id=""` solved it. Thanks